# rewrite a geometric series as a power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Is there an easy way to rewrite the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \frac{81x^3}{(81x^4-1)^2}$$ as a power series?

Comment: Yes. This is $\frac{1}{x}\frac{u}{(1-u)^2}$ where $u=(3x)^4$. The fraction $\frac{u}{(1-u)^2}$ can be expressed as a power series quite easily (hint: the expression is $u$ times the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-u}$).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly streamlined version of anon's comment: 
$$
 \frac{81x^3}{(81x^4-1)^2} =   \frac{1}{4}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-81x^4}\right) 
$$
The expression in  parentheses is easy to expand: 
$$
\frac{1}{1-81x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty ( 81 x^{4 })^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  81^n x^{4n}
$$ 
Then differentiate term-by-term, and you are done.